# How to cast a void pointer to another type of pointer and assign it

Tags: c++, pointers

What I've tried:

Main.h

```
#pragma once

union TBufferRec
{
    int ID;
};
extern TBufferRec BufferRec;
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Main.h"

void CastPointer(void* PPointer)
{
    static_cast<TBufferRec*>(*BufferRec) = static_cast<TBufferRec*>(PPointer);
}
```

Errors:

> E0349 no operator "*" matches these operands

> C2679 binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'TBufferRec *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

How can I make `BufferRec` point to another address?

**SOLVED:**

Very informative feedback, thank you.

Main.h

```
#pragma once

union TBufferRec
{
    int ID;
};
extern union TBufferRec* BufferRec;
extern void MovePointer(void* PPointer);
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Main.h"

TBufferRec* BufferRec;

void MovePointer(void* PPointer)
{
    BufferRec = static_cast<TBufferRec*>(PPointer);
}
```

Comment: You can't, its not a pointer, its an object.

Comment: You can't. It's not possible to move an object in the memory.

Comment: How do I make it a pointer?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you want global object `BufferRec` to have a different address? Do you just want to reassign that object maybe?

Comment: You tried this to achieve what?

Comment: I have to assign one union variable to another through pointers/addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it step by step, solving one problem at a time and building upon previous solituons.

Suppose you have two pointers to `TBufferRec` objects, how to assign one object to the other? Given a pointer, you access the pointed-to object by *dereferencing* (the unary asterisk operator).

```
void assign0(TBufferRec* lhs, TBufferRec* rhs) {
   *lhs = *rhs;
}
```

OK now one of the pointers is still pointing to a `TBufferRec`, but has type `void*`, what to do? You convert a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type by *casting*.

```
void assign1(TBufferRec* lhs, void* rhs) {
   assign0(lhs, static_cast<TBufferRec*>(rhs));
   // or the same as
   // *lhs = *static_cast<TBufferRec*>(rhs);
}
```

OK now instead of a pointer, you have an actual variable, what to do? Given a variable, you obtain a pointer to it by using the *address-of* operator (the unary ampersand, the opposite of dereferencing)

```
void assign2(void* rhs) {
   extern TBufferRec lhs;
   assign1(&lhs, rhs);
   // or the same as
   // assign0(&lhs, static_cast<TBufferRec*>(rhs));
   // or the same as
   // *(&lhs) = *static_cast<TBufferRec*>(rhs);
   // or the same as
   // lhs = *static_cast<TBufferRec*>(rhs);
}
```

Comment: Very informative. Thank you. Can't I simply use `lhs = static_cast<TBufferRec*>(rhs);` ? I want to literally change the pointer of lhs to point to rhs.

Comment: Changing the pointer is something very different from changing the object it poibtts to.

Comment: I understand, my question can be misinterpreted. I forgot to place the asterisk reference to TBufferRec initially.

Answer (score 1):

```
extern TBufferRec BufferRec;
```

This means that BufferRec is union TBufferRec.

The function make no sense. I'll explain what every part does:

```
void MovePointer(void* PPointer)
```

The function receives pointer to void (some kind of generic pointer)

```
static_cast<TBufferRec*>(PPointer);
```

PPointer is casted to be a pointer to TBufferRec

```
(*BufferRec)
```

You can't do this. You go to the value which the pointer BufferRec is pointing to, but, BufferRec isn't a pointer, it is a union. You probably meant to write:

```
static_cast<TBufferRec*>(&BufferRec) = static_cast<TBufferRec*>(PPointer);
```

But this also make no sense because you cast pointer to TBufferRec to be pointer to TBufferRec. So what you really meant to do is to make the BufferRec a pointer and in addition, not to cast it:

```
   extern TBufferRec BufferRec;
void MovePointer(void* PPointer)
{
    static_cast<TBufferRec*>(*BufferRec) = static_cast<TBufferRec*>(PPointer);
}
```

When you use extern it means that it this variable should be allocated in another file without extern (you **must** understand extern before using it).

Comment: I'm using `extern` in order to make the variable available to other files. What I want to do is feed a raw address to function `MovePointer` and assign that address to the pointer of the union variable. So, basically I want to assign a union variable to another. "Link" them if you will.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to assign one union variable to another through pointers/addresses.

```
void AssignByPointer(TBufferRec *lhs, const TBufferRec *rhs) {
    *lhs = *rhs;
}

AssignByPointer(&BufferRec, &LocalBufferRec);

// or simpler without pointers/addresses
BufferRec = LocalBufferRec;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comments and particularly the one replying to Ziv Kvatinsky I think you've misunderstood what `extern` does.

This:

```
extern TBufferRec BufferRec;
```

declares to the compiler that `BufferRec` is defined in another source file and during the link phase will be resolved to a definition of the symbol. If it isn't exactly one definition there'll be an error (Symbol not found or duplicate Symbol found).

That has nothing to do with whether you can change the address of BufferRec at run-time and because it's declared as an object (albeit in another source file) you can't.

You can't change the address *of* a variable at run-time. You can change variables that are addresses (called pointers). It may help to re-read that a couple of times.

So, I'm not sure what you're doing but it would make more sense to declare a variable that is an address (a pointer) since you appear to want to specify where data is at run-time.

```
extern TBufferRec* BufferRecPointer;
```

in your Main.h and

```
TBufferRec* BufferRecPointer;

void MovePointer(TBufferRec &BufferRec)
{
    BufferRecPointer=&BufferRec;
}
```

in your Main.cpp.

I don't know what you've got going on with the `void *` but it looks like something that will blow up in your face.

```
void MovePointer(void *PPointer){
    BufferRecPointer=static_cast<TBufferRec*>(PPointer);
}
```

would mean the compiler will let you pass practically any pointer to `MovePointer` and have it treated (elsewhere in your program - unshown) as a valid location to store a non-trivial object of type TBufferRec both size, alignment and non-trivial initialisation of the `std::sting` member will almost certainly cause issues if not handled correctly.

Comment: The only reason I want to use `extern` is so I can access the union object from other files. From what I understand I have to declare in .h file and define in .cpp file. Correct me if I'm wrong. I'll have to re-read your answer regarding pointers. Pointers are very confusing. You may be right that what I'm doing with `void*` will probably blow in my face, haha. I omitted this part since it is not directly related. I'm trying to link or sync a Delphi record with a C++ union, provided that both exist in the same memory space.

Comment: Well, in the end everything worked!